# Fill and 2D array from .txt file

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, text, freeze

So, I need to look through the file and fill and 2d array with data from the file. I couldn't figure any better way to do that than this, but this code just completly freezes. Here's the code.

The idea is that I'm gonna look through all of the text in a source file, then I'm gonna check if a line contains something I need and, if so, I will make additions to my 2D array, that I will then write to a different txt file.

```
string[,] FileBase = new string[100,100];
DateTime Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
string time = Date.ToString();
time = time.Replace(':', '.');
string ReportPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Report from " + time + ".txt";
        
int Value = 0;
int i = 0, j = 0;
string item;
int controlD = 0;
int sensor = 0;
int p = 0;
bool loadcell = false;
bool possensor = false;
int smth = 0;
string curr = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
curr = curr.Remove(0, curr.IndexOf("RCU") + 3); 
int current = Convert.ToInt32(curr);

string localpath = path + "\\control\\RCU" + curr + "\\cfg\\RCU" + curr + ".cfg"; 
FileStream file1 = new FileStream(localpath, FileMode.Open); 
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file1);
while ((item = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    for (i = p; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 1000; i++)
        {
            if (item.Contains("Signal_Sensor"))
            {
                sensor++;
                FileBase[i, j] = "Signal_SensorA" + sensor;
                break;
            }
            else if (item.Contains("Signal_PositionA"))
            {
                controlD++;
                FileBase[i, j] = "Signal_PositionA" + controlD;
                break;
            }
            else if (item.Contains("Division") && (controlD != 0))
            {
                FileBase[i, j] = "Division";
                FileBase[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToString(CommaClear(Value));
                break;
            }
            else if (item.Contains("LowerLimitExternal"))
            {
                FileBase[i, j] = "LowerLimitExternal";
                FileBase[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToString(CommaClear(Value));
                break;
            }
            else if (item.Contains("UpperLimitExternal"))
            {
                FileBase[i, j] = "UpperLimitExternal";
                FileBase[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToString(CommaClear(Value));
                break;
            }
            else if (item.Contains("LowerLimit"))
            {
                FileBase[i, j] = "LowerLimit";
                FileBase[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToString(CommaClear(Value));
                break;
            }
            else if (item.Contains("UpperLimit"))
            {
                FileBase[i, j] = "UpperLimit";
                FileBase[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToString(CommaClear(Value));
                break;
            }
            else if (item.Contains("LoadCell"))
            {
                loadcell = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (item.Contains("PositionSensor"))
            {
                possensor = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (item.Contains("EnableSensorA" + smth))
            {
                smth++;
                FileBase[i, j] = "EnableSensorA" + smth;
                FileBase[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToString(CommaClear(Value));
                break;
            }
            else if (item.Contains("InvertSensorA"))
            {
                smth++;
                FileBase[i, j] = "InvertSensorA" + (smth - 3);
                FileBase[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToString(CommaClear(Value));
                break;
            }
            if (smth ==6)
            {
                smth = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        p = i;
        break;
    }
}

reader.Close();
File.Create(ReportPath);
FileStream ReportFill = new FileStream(ReportPath, FileMode.Open);
StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(ReportFill);
WriteArray();
reader1.Close();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it freeze on a specific method or does it just loop forever?

Comment: @Ben, it freezes after first full iteration. It check the first line in a source file, that just stops.